# Glitch with CollapsingToolbarLayout when popping up a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-transitions

I have a fragment A with a CollapsingToolbarLayout containing a view that collapses when scrolling the page.

At the end of the page, a button navigates to another fragment B.

When I press back on fragment B, fragment B is removed from the navigation stack and fragment A is shown again from the previous position (scroll at the bottom).

Right now everything is ok, but the toolbar of fragment A is initially visible and then collapses during the transition, even if it should not be visible.

[image: Glitch]

This is the layout of Fragment A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?android:colorBackground"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="70dp"
            app:statusBarScrim="?android:colorBackground">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/chevron_back"
                app:navigationIconTint="#00ff00" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/content_padding"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/short_description"
                style="@style/body_gray"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
                android:text="Next" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is its code:

```
class FragmentA: Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentABinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.next.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_A_to_B)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is the action used for the navigation:

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_A_to_B"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentb"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pop_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/pop_out"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
```

This is the video of the glitch: https://youtube.com/shorts/0UKtAwOSZQI

This is a minimal project that replicates the problem: https://mega.nz/file/lq5AEY6T#A-PxuVcWGDLSSktGHLwmtfMBgfUYu659EF7LbP770S8

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if the action animation are removed?

Comment: Yes, I can see them even without animation. With animations is just more visible than without

Comment: I'd built a demo, but I couldn't manage to reproduce this issue

Comment: it is happening because when we press back the ```onResume``` method calls and due to this it restores the previous instance state of the fragment you need to add additional condition to it so it could always move to the top or in worst case you have create a new fragment to control it.

Comment: @Zain just attached a minima example that shows the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem causing that glitch is that the scrim animation of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is enabled by default, so it takes time to fade out the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` color.

This can be solved by disabling the scrim animation by setting its duration to 0 using [`app:scrimAnimationDuration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout#setScrimAnimationDuration(long)) attribute:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ....>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        ....>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="0">
            
...
```

### Edit

Well, although disabling the scrim animation will solve the issue, but it will raise another whenever the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` get collapsed or expanded by dragging it up or down; so we need to conditionally disable the scrim animation.

Now remove the `app:scrimAnimationDuration="0"` from the layout.

We need to keep the scrim animation ON by default, but only when we returned back from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A` we need to disable it and re-enable it again:

```
// In Fragment A
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    // Make sure to save that on a permanent storage like ViewModel to avoid losing it.
    val duration = binding.collapsingToolbar.scrimAnimationDuration 
   
    // Disable the animation
    binding.collapsingToolbar.scrimAnimationDuration = 0

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        // Re-Enable the animation
        binding.collapsingToolbar.scrimAnimationDuration = duration
    }, duration)
}
```

Comment: Turns out that [the default scrim animation duration is 600](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6ba61c5/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.java#79)

Comment: Thanks, that works, but now the scrim animation is gone.

I used your solution with the one of @Vinay

`binding.appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
      val isToolbarVisible = abs(verticalOffset) != appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
       binding.collapsingToolbar.scrimAnimationDuration = if (isToolbarVisible) 600 else 0
}`

In this way I keep the scrim animation when the toolbar is visible, but after is goes invisible I remove it; when coming back from FragmentB, the animation will behave correctly

Comment: @P1x I just edited the answer for that, thanks to have a look

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in your First Fragment-

```
binding.appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
    val isToolbarVisible = abs(verticalOffset) != appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
    binding.topAppBar.isVisible = isToolbarVisible
}
```

In the `addOnOffsetChangedListener`, we check the `verticalOffset` to determine if the toolbar is fully collapsed or not. If the absolute value of `verticalOffset` is equal to the `totalScrollRange`, it means the toolbar is fully collapsed, and we hide it by setting its visibility to false. Otherwise, we show the toolbar by setting its visibility to true.

Comment: This isn't working :(

Comment: I have tried your code, and the issue does not show when we use addOnOffsetChangedListener, but it does show when we do not use it.

Comment: I could make your solution almost work setting and id to the other view (the red one) and, in your code using

binding.appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
    val isToolbarVisible = abs(verticalOffset) != appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
    binding.otherView.isVisible = isToolbarVisible
}

The glitch is still visible but it is much better than before, as it starts as visible but it gets hidden quickly.

Comment: Hi, I mixed your solution with the one from Zain.
Using both of them perfectly fix the behaviour.

I could reward only one of you, so I gave it to Zain as I think he got the specific problem, even if your solution was somehow working. But I want to thank you too for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'match_parent' to `NestedScrollView`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: No, that didn't work :(